# My entry will only return as 0. (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *


def generator(n):
    print((n*(n+1))/2)

root = Tk()

userText = int()
entryBox = Entry(root, textvariable=userText)
entryBox.grid(column=0)
generateButton = Button(root, text='Generate')
generateButton.grid(row=0, column=1)


def leftClick(event):
    generator(userText)


generateButton.bind('<Button-1>', leftClick)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm using this code to practice using Tkinter by making an interface where I can input a number 'n' and click the generate button to generate the 'n'th term in the triangular number sequence. I've almost figured out how to use this entry box feature correctly, but when I put in any number after running this code, I get a '0.0' returned. Also, I tried using `IntVar()` instead of `int()` for the userText, but `IntVar()` just returned this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IntVar' and 'int'`. Why is this not working and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that it is not working is because the `textvariable` that you are associating with `entryBox` is not an instance of a Tkinter variable class: BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar. Updates to these variable classes are tracked by Tkinter, and widgets updated accordingly. Standard Python variables such as `int` are not tracked.

So, you can use `userText.get()` to pass the *value* of an `IntVar` (an integer) to your generator function:

```
userText = IntVar()

def leftClick(event):
    generator(userText.get())
```

Alternatively you could forget the `userText` variable and get the current value from `entryBox` directly:

```
entryBox = Entry(root)
def leftClick(event):
    generator(int(entryBox.get()))
```

but I think that the former is slightly better.